# Get, Update, and Change Current Working Directory in C++

Tags: c++

so I'm now taking a college course to learn more about C++ and I have been experimenting with it for a bit now. Anyways, I'm trying to virtualize a command shell via C++. I have a bit of a problem though, I'm trying to do something where it will allow me to get the CWD and update it every time a new command has been submitted and then if the command 'cd' was used, it will manually change the current working directory and update it to the new selected one in the C++ code. Here is the code I'm having trouble with..

```
while (true) {
    std::string cmd; std::wcout << name; std::cout << "@" << CurDir << "> "; // This is designed to print out the entire command shell ex:(willi@C:\development\ConsoleApplication1\Debug> )
    std::getline(std::cin, cmd); // Accept a string and use as our command to execute
    if ((cmd.substr(0, cmd.find(" ")) == "cd")) // Check if the inputted string contains the command 'cd' in it
        _chdir(cmd.substr(3, cmd.find(" ")).c_str()); // Change current working directory via C++ code
    else
        std::cout << exec(cmd.c_str()) << std::endl; // If 'cd' wasn't detected in the command to execute, just pipe it over to our execution method
}
```

I'm using this line to get the current directory:

```
const std::string CurDir = std::experimental::filesystem::current_path().string();
```

I can't seem to get it right though. I want to be able to do this in my applet:

```
user1@C:\development\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1> dir
 ...
user1@C:\development\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1> cd ..
user1@C:\development\ConsoleApplication1> dir
 ...
user1@C:\development\ConsoleApplication1>
```

The thing is that it just won't go through with what I need it to do.
I found some C# code that does pretty much the exact same thing if I can just find out how to implement it in C++ that would be fantastic!

https://github.com/BlackVikingPro/aresdoor/blob/master/Program.cs#L65

Comment: Unrelated: Since you are using `std::experimental::filesystem::current_path` to get, why not also use it to set?

Comment: *it just won't go through with what I need it to do* is not a useful problem description. You've not described a specific problem, and you've not asked any sort of question. What **specifically** is the difficulty you're having, and what **specific problem** can we help you with today?

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, ok never mind I found a way to capture the current working directory programatically by changing this:

```
std::string cmd; std::wcout << name; std::cout << "@" << CurDir << "> ";
```

to:

```
std::string cmd; std::wcout << name; std::cout << "@"; std::wcout << _getcwd(NULL, 0); std::cout << "> ";
```

I guess the CurDir variable only captured the programs directory in which it was launched in? Anyways, I got the solution, use as you wish :)

Comment: Wait, found another bug. I can leave the cwd by doing `cd ..` but I can't go back into a directory by doing `cd C:\development` and so on. Not only does it not take me into the new directory, but now it doesn't even show it as if it didn't even change -_-.

Comment: Parsers are rarely as easy as they look. You might want to draw up a little flow chart or state machine to help you track all of the fun deviant cases.